# How can i run phpunit tests from excluded list?

Tags: php, phpunit

i have this configuration in `phpunit.xml`.
My concern is that I don't want to run a test when `phpuint` command is executed.

```
<testsuite name="Unit">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Feature">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    <exclude>./tests/Feature</exclude>
</testsuite>
```

i need to run Feature test separatly, Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I do the same of limiting the tests that are being run - the larger set only runs when I specifically run all the tests, and less than half for a normal, quick-run.

The trick is to add `@group` annotations to the test sources (on a class or method basis) - so, for example:

```
/** 
 * @group feature
 * @group large
 */
public function testFeatureThatTakesTime() {}
```

Now, if you run `vendor/bin/phpunit --exclude-group feature ./tests/` it will *not* run that test. I have that, and some other command-line parameters in a shell script, and there are other ways for me to run *all* of my tests.

Comment: To run a subset of tests using the `@group` annotations you would use the `--group` option and pass in the name of your group, e.g., `phpunit --group yourTestGroupName`

Comment: Does it work worked when it in exclude tag?
I want to be excluded from only command `phpunit` and run separately.